# Create a SQL report associating thousands of records

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a newbie in Oracle SQL and i'm trying to do the following:

I have a list of products with sales only on a certain weeks of the year.
I'm just triying to create a whole report of sales for the year and fill those weeks with no sales with zeroes, but preserving the product ID as identifier.

Trying to create that report, i'm starting trying to create a table with all the weeks of the year and de product ID, the problem is that there are thousands of products. I'm trying to get something like:

```
WEEK_YR   PRODUCT_ID
------    ----------
2018011   Product 1
2018012   Product 1
...
2018053   Product 1
...
2018124   Product 1
...
2018011   Product 2
2018012   Product 2
...
2018053   Product 2
...
2018124   Product 2
```

And then just join this table with the sales table per week, putting 0 in those  null weeks from that table.

I request your help at creating the first table, i just count with a table with the products ID and other with the list of weeks from last year

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add  a proper data sample  ..and the expected  result

Comment: A [partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) would help you here - all you need to do is create a subquery that generates the weeks you're after and partition outer join the product_ids to it.

Comment: This is a perfect situation for a Date DImension/Calendar Table. Every database should have one, because it makes queries like this a fairly simple `JOIN`.

Comment: @Shawn "every database should have one"? I dispute that. Sometimes it's more overhead to maintain a calendar table than to make one up on the fly!

Comment: @Boneist thanks a lot for your help, it went like charm and i learned something very useful. Thank you all

Comment: @MasterC Partitioned outer joins are one of my favourite features of Oracle! Not one I have to use very often, but when you do need them, they're awesome! *{:-)

Comment: @Boneist There shouldn't be a whole lot of maintenance needed on a calendar table if a little bit of though is put into planning it.

Comment: @Shawn and even a small amount of maintenance is overkill if a calendar table isn't needed, even one that's generated on the fly.

Comment: @Boneist I guess I'm not sure what maintenance would need to be done. It's not a table that will be updated often, it doesn't require a lot of space, and unless you're working with a fairly simple database with simple queries, it will be fairly useful. Same with a Numbers Table. I guess I really just can't see any real downsides to something that is essentially pretty simple after initial creation.

Comment: @Shawn well, you've got to keep the table up-to-date, so you've got to periodically add rows (and the less frequent that is, the more likely it is that it'll get forgotten about), which requires code to do the work and a scheduled job to do the work. And the job needs to be monitored to make sure it didn't error and not add rows. I'm not saying there's not a place for that, but for some databases (and not necessarily small ones), it's an unnecessary overhead. YMMV, of course, but I've worked on many databases and not all of them needed a holiday table.

Comment: @Boneist If you add enough dates to cover a conceivable time frame that you might need, it shouldn't take much more effort than the original creation. You may need to update some info about the dates (like maybe some holiday info) if that changes. But I'm not sure that big of a change would happen often or not be able to be planned. But even then, if your date range is broad enough, it's an update and not an insert of more rows. And I still think the overhead is so extremely minor that it would be far outweighed by even an occasional benefit.

Comment: In one of my current databases, I have a Date Dimension that has every day from 1Jan1950 to 31Dec2049 with about 30 cols for the definition of that day. For about 36,500 rows, that's only about 4MB of storage, including indexes. I created it a couple of years ago, and I've only had to make 1 change to it. I modified my organization's Fiscal Year definition. With that table, it's trivial to take any date in my system and tell you the last day of that day's Quarter or if it's the "st","nd","rd","th" day of the month. All it takes is a simple JOIN, even on a million+ row table. Super fast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186941/discussion-between-shawn-and-boneist).

Answer (score 0):

> I request your help at creating the first table...

You don't need to create a persistent table for that. Since Oracle 9.2 you can use CTEs (Common Table Expressions). In the example below the cte `w` is the one you are looking for:

```
with x as ( --- cte that generates numbers from 1 to 52
  select 1 as n from dual
  union all
  select n + 1 from x where n < 52
),
w as ( --- cte that generates the week_yr
  select 2018000 + n as week_yr from x
)
select -- main query now.
  w.week_yr,
  p...
from w
left join products p on p.week_yr = w.week_yr
where ...
group by ...
```

In the query above, the cte `x` generates numbers from 1 to 52. Then the cte `w` generates the `week_yr` values you need.

Finally, the main query can do what you want.